# Updating Multiple rows in MS Access c#

Tags: c#, database, syntax, oledb, ms-access-2013

I am Trying to Update multiple rows in a MS Access DB But every time it gives ERROR IN UPDATE SYNTAX here's my code

```
cn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source =C:\\Users\\Kalpesh\\Desktop\\Entry.accdb");
sqlstr = "Update Members SET Name=@Name, MobileNo=@MobileNo, Password=@Password, IDType=@IDType, IDNo=@IDNo, AmountPaid=@AmountPaid, Address=@Address, Reg Date = "+DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()+" WHERE UserName = '" + comboBox4.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'",cn);
cmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlstr, cn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", textBox19.Text.ToString());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MobileNo", textBox14.Text.ToString());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", textBox17.Text.ToString());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDType", comboBox5.SelectedItem.ToString());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDNo", textBox11.Text.ToString());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AmountPaid", textBox16.Text.ToString());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", richTextBox3.Text.ToString());

cn.Open();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("Record Updated");
cn.Close();
```

Comment: I am not an expert in Access but `Reg Date` syntax looks wrong. First, there is a space in identifier. Second, you are probably missing some punctuation around the date literal.

Comment: Update Working Code
 sqlstr = "Update Members SET [Name]=@Name, MobileNo=@MobileNo, [Password]=@Password, IDType=@IDType, IDNo=@IDNo, AmountPaid=@AmountPaid, Address=@Address, [Reg Date] = '"+DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()+"' WHERE UserName = '" + comboBox4.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'";

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Name` and `Password` are *[reserved keywords](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html)* in MS Access.

> If a reserved word is already in use, you can avoid error messages by
>   surrounding each occurrence of the word with brackets (`[ ]`). **However,
>   the best solution is to change the name to a nonreserved word**.

You need to use `Reg Date` with square brackets like `[Reg Date]` also since it has space. Parameterized your `Reg Date` and `UserName` column values as you did for other columns. Like;

```
... [Reg Date] = @reg WHERE UserName = @user ...
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reg", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", comboBox4.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `OleDbConnection` and `OleDbCommand`.

```
string conString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source =C:\\Users\\Kalpesh\\Desktop\\Entry.accdb";
using(OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(conString))
using(OleDbCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
{
  // Do your work..
}
```

Comment: Hell Yes You were right it adding [] fro name & password & single quot  for datetime worked

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no clear error message about the syntax problem, I would guess its the lack of single quotes around the date, try this:

```
RegDate = '"+DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()+"'
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here

```
 "Reg Date = "+DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()+"
```

Try this

```
 "[Reg Date] = #" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + "# "
```